# Is clustering a necessity?

Tags: least-squares, stata, clustered-standard-errors

this is a cross-post. The original question (i had to move the link to the comments to be able to include results) was posted on Statalist, the 17.2.2016.

First the question, because possibly it can be answered without regarding my specific case:

Is there a need to vce(cluster) the standard errors, even if i can detect no correlation between residuals and the cluster-variable?

In "Microeconometrics Using Stata, Cameron and Trivedi" it is said that
Cluster-robust standard errors must be used when data are clustered.
[p. 83]. Which, i would say, is the case in my case.
On the other hand, the stata manual (1) has an entry, where clustering is suggested, but ultimately discarded: "20.21.2 Correlated errors: cluster–robust standard errors".

---

Now my specific case:

I'm regressing the logarithm of charitable donations on a set of independent variables. My data consists of two combined cross-sectional datasets: one is the german socio-economic panel and the other a survey among german people considered to be "very rich". The latter is named hvid. I use the hvid-dataset to offset the undersampling of rich people in my first sample. Overall N = 5,498.

Thus, it seemed obvious to me to use the vce(cluster hvid)- option, when running my regression. The cluster-variable is a dummy-variable for the original dataset of the observation (the hvid-dataset or the socio-economic panel). It has a value of 1 if people came from the hvid-dataset and 0 elsewise.

My standard-errors become very small, when using this option. The stata-faqs state that this can be when the intracluster correlations are negative (2).

I tried to check for correlation between residuals and the rich-variable, using a ttest and a boxplot. The ttest does not reject the null hypothesis of equal mean between both clusters and the boxplot confirms this finding in my eyes:

[image]

I would say that there is no correlation between the residuals and the clustervariable. If there would be one, i would expect that the residuals would be, for example, higher in the HViD-sample then in the SOEP-sample.

One could argue that there must be some kind of correlation (a negative one), because that is what is causing the standard errors to become so small. But before i found the mentioned explanation in the stata-faqs i really had no idea as how to explain the small standard errors. So, it might be that there is still another reason for the small standard errors out there which i just haven't found yet (if someone could indicate me an explanation i would be very happy).

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Caspar

PS: I'm usually using a heckman regression to correct for the selection bias. I use the OLS here because it is so nice to have actual residuals which one can compare and because the coefficients of the OLS and the heckman are very close, so i believe the OLS is not so far off.

Edit: In the original post my code was asked so i'm giving it here too:

I'm using a loop to go through several estimation methods (OLS, Probit, Logit, Tobit, Heckman). This is what happens if i run the OLS-Code:

```
*** preparation ***
#delimit ;
global main = "c.wealth_norm##(c.wealth_norm#c.wealth_norm)
       ib0.soc_eng_2011 ib0.child_dum ib0.married c.age_norm##c.age_norm
       ib0.unempl ib1.sex ib3.casmin_comp";

global income = "c.netinc_norm##(c.netinc_norm#c.netinc_norm)";

global selection = "ib0.married ib0.unempl ib0.retired ib0.position";

#delimit cr

*** regression ***
regress lgivings ib0.hvid##($main $income $income $selection) ///
                if givings_dum == 1, vce(cluster hvid)

*** predict ***
predict latent if e(sample), xb
predict regressres if e(sample), residuals

gr box regressres, over(hvid)
ttest regressres, by(hvid)
```

[image: Results of the OLS]

Edit 2: 
Clyde Schechter and Carlo Lazzaro have explained the following to me on Statalist: 
Clustering with only two clusters is not enough at all(regarding the number of clusters), especially in a case with many right-hand variables. 
Also the fact that the f-statistic is not reported is at least suspicious.

I answered that reporting of the f-test seems to be related with clustering, but not with the cluster variable/the number of clusters. 
Please see on the Statalist for details, because i cannot add more links at the moments.

Edit 3: 
Carlo Lazzaro on Statalist answered my question if clustering is a necessity. I will leave this question still open some while to give possibility for other answers as well, though.

Carlo Lazzaro:

> Again on the necessity of clustering: if you perform a pooled OLS the assumption that within variation is not different from between variation is hardly to prove, due to serial correlation: that's why clustered standard errors are almost mandatory (unless the literature in your research field reports something different).
>   Your problem seem to rest on the best perspective from which your regression should be performed (i.e. which -id- should be investigated).

Comment: Links for references i couldnt link: (1) http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u.pdf                                                     (2) http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/standard-errors-and-vce-cluster-option/

Comment: Metrics for std devs and errors are sensitive to the number of observations, *n*. How big is your panel sample size?

Comment: N = 5,498. I also edited the question to include this.

Comment: Original question on statalist: 
http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1327259-is-clustering-a-necessity

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have only two clusters? Be aware that cluster-robust standard error may be severely biased if only few clusters are available [see Section VI here in Cameron and Miller](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/Cameron_Miller_Cluster_Robust_October152013.pdf). The thumb of rule is that you need at least 40-50 clusters to use cluster-robust inference via that option. Why don’t you just do two separate regressions with heteroscedasticity-robust standard error?

Comment: @Arne: you are right. I should add that this was mentioned on Statalist also. I will edit this as best as possible. 
To your advice: you mean one regression per cluster?

Comment: Yes, two separate regressions, one per cluster, and you can see whether you will get similar results. I think this is more the natural approach. But if results look very similar, you may also pool them to get more power and note that you also conducted separate regressions (that's my view).

Comment: But then i couldn't see "see" the influence off the clustering variable.  I'd "just" compare the two regressions?

Comment: I think the whole point is that with only two clusters you won't be able to see the influence of the clustering variable without further assumptions because given $n_{Cluster}=2$ you cannot estimate the sample covariance matrix (and adjust for possible within cluster correlation) so you need to make a more subtle argument that both clusters are comparable (and perhaps may be pooled), e.g. that confidence intervals are comparable across clusters for the same variables.

Comment: Ok, one last point(i have a message here, asking to avoid extended discussions in the comments;)): Your are totally right about the covariance matrix. The  clusters are very different(in size as well as content.) So i would suppose that they are not comparable(regarding the estimates) and i tried to "prove" that they are comparable in regard variance of the residuals vie the ttest and the boxplot. 
I assumed implicitly that you are talking about the point-estimates. Am i right here? Or are you referring to the variance of the residuals?